# Remove [ ] from string

Tags: java, stringbuilder

How to remove [ ] from my output?

```
String omega_str[][]  ; 
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
         for (String[] row:omega_str)
                 sb.append(Arrays.toString(row));

    String text=sb.toString();  
        System.out.println("Text : "+text);
```

My output is:

```
[-0.06409677515180673][0.12516724483856012][-0.06188844693840026][0.1542289929525214][-0.06603595481351604][0.07823062287735344][0.10161817634744892]
```

expected output

```
-0.06409677515180673 0.12516724483856012 -0.06188844693840026 0.1542289929525214 -0.06603595481351604 0.07823062287735344 0.10161817634744892
```

How to do this?

Comment: remove '[', ']' them befo appending to sb

Comment: Iff your rows always contain 1 element, `sb.append(row[0]).append(' ');` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
String text=sb.toString();
```

to

```
String text=sb.toString().replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not first produce something, then remove it. The `[...]` is the result of `Arrays.toString`. You better loop through the subarrays and print the values to the string builder.

BTW, it looks like you have only ever a single value in the subarray. (This raises the question, if you really need a 2-dimensional array.)
Anyway, if you know that there is only a single value, you do not even need a loop, just

```
sb.append(' ');
sb.append(row[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regex with `replaceAll`

```
 String str="[-0.06409677515180673][0.12516724483856012]"
            + "[-0.06188844693840026][0.1542289929525214]"
            + "[-0.06603595481351604][0.07823062287735344]"
            + "[0.10161817634744892]";
 str=str.replaceAll("[\\[|\\]]", " ");
 System.out.println(str);
```

### Output:

-0.06409677515180673  0.12516724483856012  -0.06188844693840026  0.1542289929525214  -0.06603595481351604  0.07823062287735344  0.10161817634744892

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `substring()`:

```
yourString.substring(1, yourString.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip `[ ]` before add it into StringBuilder

```
String str= Arrays.toString(row);
str= str.substring(1,str.length()-1); 
sb.append(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling .toString() to an array will always generate such output, so I'd suggest you to replace "[]"with an empty string "" after calling .toString() on an array like this:

```
line.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

but it's a good solution only for short strings due to performance issuses.

Answer (score 1):

try `replaceAll` with escape characters:

```
String str = "[-0.06409677515180673][0.12516724483856012][-0.06188844693840026][0.1542289929525214][-0.06603595481351604][0.07823062287735344][0.10161817634744892]";
str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick for you.

```
for (String[] row:omega_str) {
  for(String val : row) {
      sb.append(val + " ");
  }
}

String text=sb.toString();  
System.out.println("Text : "+text);
```

as @Ingo suggested don't produce something which you want to delete

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using `regex` in order to remove what I don't like from the `toString` method is not a good approach to the problem.
I will simply create a method in your class with a good name (i.e. print....) like this:

```
public static void printArray(String[][] array) {
        System.out.print("Text :");
        for (String[] row : array)
            for (String element : row)
                System.out.print(" " + element);
    }
```

And simply call:

```
printArray(omega_str);
```

Using this solution you don't have to use either the `StringBuilder` instance.

Ciao!